# formula field gets updated based on a checkbox

Tags: formula-field

I am new to SF. I have a requirement where I am creating a Formula field. 
Basically I have three checkboxes, Check box1, Checkbox 2, Checkbox 3. I want to say something like

If Checkbox1=true, "Term1"
else if Checkbox2=True,"term 2
else "term 3"

Please let me know how to accomplish this.
Thanks.

Comment: The Help link on the formula editor page is actually very helpful and has a lot of examples.

Answer (score 3):

Formula fields can contain IF statements and I recommend reading the formula help, which is quite good documentation. IF statements work in the formula editor like they do in almost every programming language IF ( Evaluation Criteria returns boolean, Value if true, value if false ) and these IF statements can be nested inside each other.

```
IF(Checkbox1,"Term 1", IF(Checkbox2, "Term 2", "Term 3"))
```

With Checkbox1 being the API Name of the field, something like Checkbox1__c

Comment: so if checkbox1 and 2 are false it will pick 3 right?

Comment: This seems to follow the words, but I don't know where Checkbox 3 is supposed to come in.

Comment: got it, I need to word it better

Comment: The logic of this formula follows your logic and will evaluate from left to right. If Checkbox1 is true, show Term 1, if it is false, then evaluate if Checkbox 2 is true and show Term 2, if Checkbox2 is false, show Term 3 as the default value if both Checkbox 1 and 2 are false.

Comment: so I know this might be silly for me to ask but I will ask anyway.. what if I had it like if chbox 1=true then "term1, if chkbox 2=true then term 2, if checkbox 3=true then term 3

Comment: Anytime you have an IF statement, you need to provide a value if true and a value if false. What would you value be if all of them were false, null?

Comment: @QKA You can nest another if in the 2nd if so IF(Checkbox1,"Term 1", IF(Checkbox2, "Term 2", "Term 3")) would become IF(Checkbox1,"Term 1", IF(Checkbox2, "Term 2", IF(Checkbox3, "Term 3", ""))) With the final else being an empty string.

Comment: yes, and I eventually figured it out, thanks alot all of you for helping me.